# How to change language of tablet on button click?

Tags: android, application-settings

i use this following code to change language in my app

```
        if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("en")){
        Locale locale = new Locale("en");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale; 
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        homeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.accueil_en);
    }
    else {
        Locale locale = new Locale("fr");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale; 
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        homeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nouveau_home0);
    }
```

But when i think my language doesn't change because my keyboard always still in default language (french). How can i change language in my app and be sure that keyboard change too.

please help

Comment: 4 localization u can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086374/changing-android-application-language/21087465#21087465

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following in your manifest file?

```
<supports-screens
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true"
/>
```

And also you need to call `setContentView` after the button click. Or call `onCreate(null)`;

Comment: you need to call either setContentView or onCreate(null)